# Ember on Loading the application

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to get some data from the server when the application loads. What I want to do is to store that data somewhere in Ember Models or Objects and then I want to access that data throughout my application.

Any thoughts on how to do that? Should I store the data in a model or object? Where should I call that api from the server? In application route?

Answer (score 0):

In my App I do this by using localStorage; if you need to load some data at application start, the activate hook of ApplicationRoute could be a good place:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    activate: function() {
        var data= //here do what you need to get your data, such as a request to your server...
        localStorage.data = data;
    }
}
```

Then wherever you need to read your data, you can do var data = localStorage.data

If you want that your data is loaded at the very start of your App, you can use the Application Initializer:

```
//App initialization
Ember.Application.initializer({
    initialize: function(container, application) {
        var data= //here do what you need to get your data, such as a request to your server...
        localStorage.data = data;
    }
});
```

Comment: Is the active hook the first thing called before anything else is called?